# What is difference between {:.4e} and {:2.4} in Python scientific notation

Tags: python, string, format, scientific-notation

I can't quite understand what the difference is between the two print statements below for the number I am trying to express in scientific notation.  I thought the the bottom one is supposed to allow 2 spaces for the printed result, and move the decimal place 4 times, but the result I get does not corroborate that understanding. As far as the first one, What does 4e mean?

```
>>> print('{:.4e}'.format(3454356.7))
3.4544e+06

>>> print('{:2.4}'.format(3454356.7))
3.454e+06
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that the `2`, the field width in `'{:2.4}'`, is ignored because the data can't fit in two characters.

Comment: Had it been a significantly larger size, say `'{:10.4}'`, Python would have prefixed spaces as needed to achieve that number of characters (`' 3.454e+06'`). Inserting a `0` will change the prefix character to `0`: `'{:012.4}'.format(3454356.7)` gives `'0003.454e+06'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example , `4e` means, 4 decimal places in scientific notation. You can come to know that by doing

```
>>> print('{:.4e}'.format(3454356.7))
3.4544e+06
>>> print('{:.5e}'.format(3454356.7))
3.45436e+06
>>> print('{:.6e}'.format(3454356.7))
3.454357e+06
```

In the second example, `.4` , means 4 significant figures. And `2` means to fit the whole data into 2 characters

```
>>> print('{:2.4}'.format(3454356.7))
3.454e+06
>>> print('{:2.5}'.format(3454356.7))
3.4544e+06
>>> print('{:2.6}'.format(3454356.7))
3.45436e+06
```

Testing with different value of `2`

```
>>> print('-{:20.6}'.format(3454356.7))
-         3.45436e+06
```

You can learn more [from the python documentation on `format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to produce a float, you will have to specify the float type:

```
>>> '{:2.4f}'.format(3454356.7)
'3454356.7000'
```

Otherwise, if you don’t specify a type, Python will choose `g` as the type for which precision will mean the precision based on its [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures), the digits *before* and *after* the decimal point. And since you have a precision of `4`, it will only display 4 digits, falling back to scientific notation so it doesn’t add false precision.

> The *precision* is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'f'` and `'F'`, or **before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'g'` or `'G'`**. For non-number types the field indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters will be used from the field content. The precision is not allowed for integer values.

([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), emphasis mine)

Finally, note that the width (the `2` in above format string) includes the *full width*, including digits before the decimal point, digits after it, the decimal point itself, *and* the components of the scientific notation. The above result would have a width of 12, so in this case, the width of the format string is simply ignored.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  I understand now.  Thank you.